# Bootstrap 4: Prevent div from jumping to new line when button text exceeds remaining space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a navbar with Bootstrap 4 which will consist on a logo in upper left and a user button in upper right which have to take the remaining space from the logo to right and shouldn't make the button container div jump to new line when the text is longer than available space and instead make an ellipsis on the text (the toggler icon shouldn't dissapear, the ellipsis should only affect the text) but keep the button (now resized) on the same line as logo.

Then, there will be a menu (some navbar links) on the second line plus a language selector dropdown, but this is another subject, I mention it only as reference.

In the image you will see not only that button is jumping to new line but is also taking 100% width when what I'm expecting to achieve is that width adjust to text.

[image]

In the next image you can see more or less what I'd like to achieve, and I say "more or less" because as I'm not being able to achieve it, it has problems, you don't see the button toggler icon and if you click it the dropdown menu neither appears. but you can see the ellipsis and the text truncated that is ok.

[image]

```css
.nav-item {
  text-align: right;
}

.selectpicker {
  font-size: 24px !important;
}


/* *** */

.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.long-and-truncated {
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.short-and-fixed {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.long-and-truncated-with-child {
  flex: 1;
}

.long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  /* or some value */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid #fff">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <div class="col-* pl-0 pr-0 mr-2" style="border: 1px solid red">
      <a class="navbar-brand mr-0" href="{{cirsaApp.cirsaWebsiteUrl}}" target="_blank" style="border: 1px solid #fff">
        <img src="http://whatson.ae/dubai/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/img-world-of-adventure-10.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col pr-0 pl-0 text-truncate" style="border: 1px solid red; ">
      <!-- User menu -->
      <div class="dropdown flex-parent" style="border: 1px solid #fff; " *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle long-and-truncated" data-toggle="dropdown" id="userDropdown">
              {{userName | async}}
            </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a [routerLink]="['/login']" class="dropdown-item">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bro you code worked fine on my system! Let me see

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Krishanu. I use latest Chrome, then hit F12 to open console and hit the mobile / desktop switcher to display in mobile view and you will see the problem, when you start resizing browser window, in a moment the buttom div jumps to new line.